# How can I combine png's with transparent backgrounds in appengine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to combine more pngs having transparent backgrounds into a single image that would later be served to the client. How can I achieve that in appengine? Seems like the api doesn't work, because transparency isn't honored. Here's my snippet:

```
            ArrayList<Composite> comps = new ArrayList<Composite>();
            comps.add(ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(getImageFromStaticFile("imgs/odontogram/dente_colore/dente_colore_11.png"), 0, 0, 1, Anchor.TOP_LEFT));
            comps.add(ImagesServiceFactory.makeComposite(getImageFromStaticFile("imgs/odontogram/dente_colore/dente_colore_12.png"), 10, 0, 1, Anchor.TOP_LEFT));
            long color = 0xFFFFFFFFL;
            Image resImg = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService().composite(comps, 429, 189, color);
            response.getOutputStream().write(resImg.getImageData());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a more in-depth research on the question of transparency and found out that the problem exists only using the development server. In production seems to be fine. It's still pretty annoying, because I have to wait 20 mins for the deploy to finish, but at least it works...

Thanks to all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the Python Image Library (PIL) which is available under Python 2.7.  It looks like your App is Java, but you can deploy Python code to a different version.

Answer (score 0):

If the alpha channels are not being preserved and your output encoding format supports alpha channels (i.e. not jpeg) then this sounds like a bug.

Can you file an issue in the issue tracker and attach sample images and a code snippet?

Thanks